# Prevent Session Hijacking with copying all metadata from a browser

Tags: authentication, session-management, authorization

For example, I'm signed in to my Gmail account. If I copy all data from all the places that Chrome uses (localstorage, all the cookies, all temp folders and so on) to another PC.

- How does Google prevent my old session from hijacking?
- Let's make it harder for Google, I made a copy of my laptop with TimeMachine (or something else for Windows/Linux) and this snapshot captured my browser when I was signed in to Google. I recover the snapshot on another laptop. Essentially, I have two exact laptops. Would I have two valid sessions on both laptops?

Comment: This question is very specific to how Google does it and what is possible with it. I'm not sure if this can be answered without knowing internals only known to Google. In my opinion a more general question which asks a) how one could prevent session hijacking in this case in general and b) if this is a relevant threat scenario in the first place would be more useful. As for your second point regarding duplicating a session - just try it.

Comment: I believe Google uses a certificate tied to the browser/user.  It may also be tied to the hardware at some level.  When Chrome installs it may read system info and probably hardware info to generate a unique sort of key which may be used for the cert.  I'm guessing that even making a snapshot won't work... but it's an interesting experiment.  If it doesn't work at first you may need to transfer and activate the Windows license first... that may update what would be needed for DPAPI encrypted values that Google uses. (Linux would be less secure.)